# vbscript regex match two string

Tags: regex, vbscript, string-matching

How do I use vbscript to find two texts that match within a singe line? For example:

```
This UserName is Logged on already.
```

How do I search for "UserName" and "Logged on"?

Comment: Please post a code attempt of yours. Also consider using a service like http://rubular.com/ to try it yourself.

Comment: hi Sunny, thanks for sending the link [rubular.com](http://rubular.com), it's very good. I had tried gged\b it matches logged and i put \w (username) it matches username but how do i combined those two commands? Thanks.

Comment: You can combine the command using "OR" which looks like `|`.

Comment: Hi Sunny if i used "OR" it will only find either one right? How do i use the AND operator? I had tried (?= UserName) (?= Logged\son) in rubular.com but it says "No Matches Found". What should be the correct way of doing it?

Comment: It sort of depends exactly what you want. If you're to see if a string contains TWO phrases (or more) then you can use look ahead/look behind but if you can assume that every line that has username has logged on, you can just use OR and it will accomplish the same effect.

Comment: Did you try with `UserName.*Logged on` ?

Comment: Use the pattern `^This (.+) is (.+) already\.$` on a `Global` search. Capture the matches. `Username` should be in `matches(0).submatches(0)`, `Logged on` in `matches(0).submatches(1)`.

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions are probably overkill in this case. I'd suggest using [`InStr()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c%28v=vs.84%29) for this kind of check:

```
s = "This UserName is Logged on already."
If InStr(s, "UserName") > 0 And InStr(s, "Logged on") > 0 Then
  '...
End If
```

You can wrap `InStr()` in a helper function if you want to make the check a bit better readable:

```
s = "This UserName is Logged on already."
If Contains(s, "UserName") And Contains(s, "Logged on") Then
  '...
End If

Function Contains(str1, str2)
  Contains = False
  If InStr(str1, str2) > 0 Then Contains = True
End Function
```